# How to re-calculate the time-stamps (from the past) to UTC using bash

Tags: bash, datetime

I have a text file (data.txt) that contains time-stamps expressed in my local Time-Zone (CEST):

Example:

```
2015-05-13   23:12:11
2015-05-14   00:13:23
2015-05-14   07:12:13
2015-05-14   08:34:45
2015_05-14   19:39:44
```

I have to write a bash script that re-calculates these time-stamps to UTC (CEST=UTC+2hrs).

The expected output file:

```
2015-05-13   21:12:11
2015-05-13   22:13:23
2015-05-14   05:12:13
2015-05-14   06:34:45
2015_05-14   17:39:44
```

I used the `date` command with many options (`-d` , `-u`) with no effect. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I can generate your example via exactly the options you've tried:

```
$ date +"%F  %T" -d "2015-05-13   23:12:11 CEST" -u
2015-05-13  21:12:11
```

Stick that in a loop and you'll be able to operate on the whole file.